# Questions about Envelope Design to Print using Home Printer?

Tags: print-design

I have some C5 sized envelopes and I would like to create a design that I can print on it using my printer. Using the correct size that the internet gave me for a C5 envelope, I create a rough sample as a test.

What happened is that there is a about an inch of a gap on all four corners as if the design is smaller than the size I was given... When I printed again using the full size setting rather than "fit to frame" (as I did before), the top and bottom reached nearly the end (which was exactly where I wanted it to go) while both left and right sides had again this inch gap completely cutting of the design.

I saw by chance that choosing to print on a C5 document size from my PDF print settings leaves a gap for the important details like stamps and so on. Is there a way for me to overwrite the setting or simply print on the entire size of my envelope regardless of where the "important details" have to go?

I really do not know if I am using any technical term correctly so forgive me please. Hahaha if anyone has some guideline suggestions or what not, that would be great to!

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Edge to edge, or "borderless" printing is a function of the ***printer***. It's not part of any software.

If your printer does not support "borderless prints" then you can not print edge-to-edge - either manually or through the paper feed.

Often the *best* you can do at home, short of purchasing a new printer, is to design for the printer you have. If it requires a 1/4" "gap" or margin for rollers, then your design should account for that.

Comment: In this case you probably can, by feeding the envelope doubletaped to a A4. I say probably since it can also go tits up and break your printer.